# Setting config for a chrome extension ( Configuring chrome extension parameters )

Tags: configuration, google-chrome-extension

our company wants to bundle our software (a binary .exe for windows) with a simple chrome extension (content scripts only {it does not use the chrome API}).

Our binary .exe will dynamically generate a string which has to be passed to our chrome extension.

My question is - how to do that?

It seems chrome extensions lack some sort of configuration file. It would be great if I could just create an EXTENSION-ID.ini and setup the configs there or put it up on the registry (if windows).

Alternatively, I imagine I could make my binary dynamicaly build each file of our plugin (.js, .manifest) into a separate folder setting up this string we need to pass on, and then go and package this folder into an .crx and finally set windows registry key telling chrome to install this extension on initialization. (but this does not seem like a pratical solution, and still the browser would have to be restarted to get the updated string value).

I tried deploying an .crx and loading configurations from an external local file by making my extension inject into the page a script tag like this

```
<script src="file://c:/path/to/configs.js"></script>
```

but it didn't work, dont know why - maybe extensions can't access the file:// protocol ?

It looks like it is possible to access the extension local path via javascript by using chrome.extension.getURL(); but that does not help either because I guess there is no easy way to insert files inside an already packaged .crx .... and if it is not already package, I mean, if it is just a folder with the files, then chrome won`t let me install the extension. Oh my...

Answer (score 1):

Well, a think that's not how extensions are supossed to work, that's why it seems so tricky.
Extensions cannot access files in your local drive, nor read any config file, nor link via dlls.

I would send info to my extension by passing it as argument in a specific url.  Let say that http://www.abc.com fires your content script, then you should invoke http://www.abc.com?param=configurationParametersAllYouCanPutInThisLine

We can work out the details, as running the script prior the page is loaded, etc.

There may be better and more elegants method using Flash to access the local drive.

Comment: Thanks for replying - but that would not work because the parameter is a string generated by our binary program.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with that.  May be you can set your "binary program" to encodeURIComponent to convert that string in a parameter that fits URI names standard.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
chrome.extension.getURL('folder/file.js')
```

where folder is a folder IN your extension package.

Comment: 1. It is not what the OP asks for. They want their .exe to pass a dymanicaly produced string, so it couldn't be bundled in the .crx. 2. This question is over 1 year old btw.

Comment: Who cares if the question is old?  The need for people to find teh answer is never old :-)

Answer (score 0):

Native messaging may be useful for such case. It allows the extension to talk with a native app.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging